# Problems Cropping a User Selected Image

Tags: ios, objective-c

I understand this is a nooby question but why am I getting this error? I looked at Apple's Documentation and I was still a bit confused. Is it because I'm not declaring the method in the header file? What I'm trying to do is round Image View container a user has uploaded a photo in.

> No visible @interface for 'UIViewController' declares the selector 'initWithFrame:'

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self){
        self.layer.cornerRadius = roundf(frame.size.width/2.0);
        self.layer.maskToBounds = YES;
    }
    return self;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `initWithFrame:` on a `UIViewController` rather than on `UIView`. They are not the same thing. You should read the documentation on both to determine which is what.